# Rider doesn't debug with .NET 6

Tags: rider, .net-6.0

I get the following error:

`One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (CLR load callback is already in error state. A debug component is not installed. (0x80131C3C). The error code is CORDBG_E_DEBUG_COMPONENT_MISSING, or0x80131C3C.))`

Comment: Which Rider do you use?

Comment: Jetbrains Rider 2021.2.2

Comment: Try Rider 2021.3 EAP, we have fixed lots of thing regarding .NET 6 there

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to `Rider 2021.3 EAP` as pointed by [@xtmq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/904679/xtmq), solved the issue.

Answer (score 16):

You might have installed an Intel version of Rider on your Apple Silicon M1 mac.

Comment: This was the reason

Comment: Is there any way to tell which version (Intel or Silicon) we have installed? @Mostafa

Comment: @dalcam JetBrains Rider -> About JetBrains Rider, then look at Runtime version- Apple Silicon will end in "aarch64"

Answer (score 8):

This can also happen on the stable version of `Rider 2021.3.2` if you use the intel dmg instead of the Apple Silicon M1 compatible version.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me! Also as a bonus, I noticed the Apple Silicon M1 version performs much much better than intel on my machine, for obvious reasons.